# How to add new activity to existing project in Android Studio - "Project not ready"

Tags: android, android-activity

What needs to be done to add a new activity to existing project that works and compiles but has "Project not ready" in the menu. Please see the picture.

Other than that all works, so I don't know what IDE means by "Project not ready"

[image: project not ready menu sample]

Answer (score 5):

This is a little bit over a year but i thought i would provide an answer for anyone (novice like me) who may encounter the same problem.
I had the exact same problem as depicted and denoted. It was fixed by

- Cleaning the project (Build --> Clean Project)
- Sync with Gradle  ( Tools --> Android --> Sync project with Gradle files)

Comment: Check your internet access if you're not using offline mode.

Answer (score 3):

What I did to solve this was to open up specifically the Android project in a new Android studio instance (not from the flutter project, which has everything)

Note if you don't see the option to do this in your project -> flutter options
[image]

Then you can just open the folder containing the project, followed by opening up the Android project specifically from there.

Now you should get the options
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*(Not an exact answer)* Observation:

I don't know exactly what happened, but it works now, all I could notice is that gradle had some error from unclean build likely I must have had some code changes resulting in invisible compilation errors. After good build menus available again.

Please post your "observation" if you don't know exact answer.

Thanks

Comment: what did you do to make this build run ?

Comment: It was lol a year ago. I haven't use AS since whenever we have finished the project. I don't remember how I solve it, sorry. Maybe next time I'll be working with Android and have same issue and remember I have posted this question I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Activity to an android application,
you have to Extend Activity from one of your classes like this:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity
```

And add that activity to your manifest.

```
       <activity
            android:name=".ActivitySecondClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name2" >

        </activity>
```

You have to give the project time to build first. Wait a minute or two before jumping in.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by clearing the cache. (File > Invalidate caches & Restart).